# Select with NOT IN with entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to take the SQL code below and turn turn it into an EF select statement. I pretty much have it finished except I am stuck on how to do a NOT IN in entity framerwork.

MS SQL SELECT

```
SELECT * from friends as f
 WHERE (f.id NOT IN (Select friendid from users_friends where userid = 1))
   AND (f.lastname LIKE '%b%' OR f.firstname LIKE '%b%' OR f.alias LIKE '%b%')
```

My EF select without the NOT IN part

```
var friends =
    (from f in db.Friends 
     select new FriendModel()
    {
        Id = f.Id,
        Alias = f.Alias,
        CarrierId = f.CarrierId,
        CreatedOn = f.CreatedOn,
        FirstName = f.FirstName,
        LastName = f.LastName,
        Locked = f.Locked,
        PhoneNumber = f.PhoneNumber,
        SteamId = f.SteamId,
        Carrier = new CarrierModel()
        {
            CarrierName = f.Carrier.CarrierName,
            CarrierEmail = f.Carrier.CarrierEmail
        }
    }).Where(
        f => (f.Alias.Contains(query) || f.FirstName.Contains(query) || f.LastName.Contains(query)))
        .OrderBy(f => f.Alias)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
var friendIds = db.users_friends.Where(f => f.userid == 1).Select(f => f.friendid);
var friends = db.Friends.Where(f => !friendIds.Contains(f.Id) &&
                                      (f.Alias.Contains(query) ||       
                                      f.FirstName.Contains(query) || 
                                        f.LastName.Contains(query)))
                         .Select(f => new FriendModel() { ... })
                         .OrderBy(f => f.Alias)
                         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming User entity has a collection of Friend entity.

```
   .Where(f => (f.Alias.Contains(query) || f.FirstName.Contains(query) || f.LastName.Contains(query))
            && !context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u=>u.UserId == 1)
            .Friends.Any(uf=>uf.FriendId == f.FriendId))
```

If not, query the UserFriend table directly

```
   .Where(f => (f.Alias.Contains(query) || f.FirstName.Contains(query) || f.LastName.Contains(query))
            && !context.UserFriends.Any(uf=>uf.UserId == 1 && uf.FriendId == f.FriendId)
```

Comment: I am confused what the .Friends.Any part. it breaks on the .Friends?

Comment: You're looking for a user with userId == 1, and then checking if that User object does not have a friend with the same id as "f" in that query. If your DB is setup properly, User entity should have a collection of Friend entities.